# ajax editor in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have an Ajax Editor in my page:

```
<cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" width="600px"/>
```

What I want is to save the content from the Editor to my database.I tried this but it won't work:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO titlu (descriere) Values(@descriere)",con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descriere", Editor1.Content);
```

I am using C# and it's a ASP.Net web application.. Why can't I save my data?

Comment: fire up the debugger - step into it - and then if you cant't see whats wrong post the code where things are behaving differently to what you expect.

Comment: This is the part where it's behaving different..I can'y gey yyhe value from the Editor and insert it into my database

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code is something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new ...)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                    "INSERT INTO titlu (descriere) Values(@descriere)",con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descriere", Editor1.Content);
    con.Open();
    int affectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

then the line `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` will either throw an exception or return the number of affected rows - in your case it should obviously be 1.

If an exception is not being thrown then the value is being entered into the database - make sure that Editor1.Content actually contains something when it is accessed here.  Also make sure you are not swallowing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't show where you execute the SQL command. If execute the command what
error code or exception do you get?

see this example:

```
 // Given command text and connection string, asynchronously execute
    // the specified command against the connection. For this example,
    // the code displays an indicator as it is working, verifying the 
    // asynchronous behavior. 
    using (SqlConnection connection = 
               new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            int count = 0;
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
            connection.Open();

            IAsyncResult result = command.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
            while (!result.IsCompleted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting ({0})", count++);
                // Wait for 1/10 second, so the counter
                // does not consume all available resources 
                // on the main thread.
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Command complete. Affected {0} rows.", 
                command.EndExecuteNonQuery(result));
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error ({0}): {1}", ex.Number, ex.Message);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // You might want to pass these errors
            // back out to the caller.
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```